# Is it possible to run a .net library inside nodejs?

Tags: node.js, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I need to run the system.data.sqlite library which is a .net library that creates a password in the sqlite database, and for me to be able to read this database in nodejs I need to install this library. It's possible? If so how can I do this?

Comment: are you sure that there is no equivalent `npmjs` library?

Comment: Yes, I have already tested several libraries and none worked because none have this exact function

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest option may be to create a stand-alone .NET program using the desired .NET library that does what you want.  This stand-alone program can work off either command line arguments or environment variables or stdin depending what you need to send to the program in order to do its thing.

You can then run that stand-alone program from within nodejs using the [child_process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).  You can pass it arguments or retrieve results if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the C# knowledge to do this. I was seeing you have many years of experience... This library is for a sqlite database to have a password and I can't access it with node, can't you help me with this question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671779/in-nodejs-how-to-connect-an-existing-database-in-sqlite-which-has-password-i-ha)

Comment: @RodrigoBrentano - I don't understand.  You want to use a .NET library, but don't know how to program in .NET?   That's not something we can fix.  You have to learn or find a different library that works in a language you do know how to program in.

Comment: I'm making a web application with NodeJS and ReactJS that reads a sqlite database that has a password. This database comes from a larger desktop C# application that has a .net library to read the sqlite database with password. But natively sqlite has no password and I can't access it in nodejs (I have the password), I'm trying a way to be able to access the database

Comment: @RodrigoBrentano - Probably you should write a new question about your real problem with the password because there's probably a better solution than you're asking for here.  But, based on how you've written this question (where you've proposed that the ONLY solution is to use this .NET library), then my question answers that for you.  That is the way to do it.  If you want to explore other solutions for your password problem, then write a new question that explains that part of the problem and perhaps someone who knows sqlite can help you better.

Comment: @RodrigoBrentano - If you can't read the database without going through your existing  .NET program, then you have no choice, but to use the .NET library they provide which involves writing .NET code.  It's unclear how you expect to use a .NET library without writing .NET code.

Comment: Yes, I understood. But the only thing this library does is add a password to the sqlite database, which I have. Is there no way I can put this password inside my nodejs application?

Comment: @RodrigoBrentano - You've disclosed absolutely nothing about what you're actually trying to do with the password so honestly, we have no idea at all.  Like I said, if you want to write another question that describes in detail what you're trying to do with a password and shows appropriate code ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671779/in-nodejs-how-to-connect-an-existing-database-in-sqlite-which-has-password-i-ha